# Smallest number of bills program in C function-pointer issue

Tags: c, pointers

so C-programming noob here. I'm working on some practice questions, and I can't seem to figure out where I'm making a mistake on this one.

I'm pretty sure there is an error in how the pointers are being grabbed by the main function, but I've tried everything I could think of/read up on and have no idea how to resolve my problem.

Some more information about the question - the change calculation has to be a function, and I made up a program to get input from the user to then go through the function and spit out the smallest number of bills/coins used. No small change (quarters,dimes,nickels, pennies), so only int number are required.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* local variable definition of enter amount*/
    int dollars, *twenties, *tens, *fives, *toonies, *loonies;
    printf("enter amount: ");
    scanf("%d", &dollars);
    printf("\nChange for $%d is:\n", dollars);

    /* Calling pay_amount function to get smallest bills*/
    printf("$20s: %d\n", &twenties);
    printf("$10s: %d\n", &tens);
    printf("$5s: %d\n", &fives);
    printf("$2s: %d\n", &toonies);
    printf("$1s: %d\n", &loonies);
    return;
}

/*Function pay_amount declaration */
void pay_amount(int dollars, int *twenties, int *tens, int *fives, int *toonies, int *loonies)
{
    while (dollars>=0); 
    *twenties = (dollars/20);
    *tens     = ((dollars%20)/10);
    *fives    = (((dollars%20)%10)/5);
    *toonies  = ((((dollars%20)%10)%5)/2);
    *loonies  = (((((dollars%20)%10)%5)%2));
}
```

#### unwanted result example:

```
enter amount: 120

Change for $120 is:
$20s: -4196336
$10s: -4196340
$5s: -4196344
$2s: -4196348
$1s: -4196352
```

Comment: 1) `int dollars, *twenties, *tens, *fives, *toonies, *loonies;` remove `*`.

Comment: 2) call `pay_amount(dollars, &twenties, &tens, &fives, &toonies, &loonies);`

Comment: 3) `printf("$20s: %d\n", &twenties);
    printf("$10s: %d\n", &tens);
    printf("$5s: %d\n", &fives);
    printf("$2s: %d\n", &toonies);
    printf("$1s: %d\n", &loonies);` remove `&`.

Comment: You need to study about memory management, how pointers work, how to pass simple variables/pointers etc with *much* smaller programs than this. And then, try to work on this code. Hints: 1) you are using uninitialized pointers 2) you never call `pay_amount()`. 3) `while (dollars>=0); ` this is potentially an infinite loop.

Comment: 4) delete `while (dollars>=0);` and put `void pay_amount(int dollars, int *twenties, int *tens, int *fives, int *toonies, int *loonies);
` before main.

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/3tYX06)

Comment: 5) `return;` --> `return 0;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY -> Thank you! It works perfectly now. I'm still getting the hang of it all, and this has been one of my first big programs, so this is a wonderful learning experience.

Comment: @BlueMoon Trust me, I am reading up on how they work, and I am still learning. Looks like I do require more studying, but I'm glad I now see what it looks like in code. Back to the books for me!

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your program. Here are a few of them.

First, you don't want your actual variables to be pointers, but simple `int`s for you to point to:

```
int dollars, twenties, tens, fives, toonies, loonies;
```

Second, you need to pass the actual variable values to `printf`, not their addresses:

```
printf("$20s: %d\n", twenties);
printf("$10s: %d\n", tens);
printf("$5s: %d\n", fives);
printf("$2s: %d\n", toonies);
printf("$1s: %d\n", loonies);
```

Third, you don't actually call your `pay_amount` function.

Fourth, if you were to call it, it would loop indefinitely due to this completely extraneous loop that you should just remove:

```
while (dollars>=0);
```

Fifth; while this isn't actually a bug (it won't stop your program from working in any way), the additional reminder operations in `pay_amount` are redundant:

```
*twenties = (dollars/20);
*tens     = ((dollars%20)/10);
*fives    = ((dollars%10)/5);
*toonies  = ((dollars%5)/2);
*loonies  = ((dollars%2));
```

Sixth, as a note on terminology, this has nothing to do with "function pointers", which signify pointers that point to functions, rather than pointers that are passed to functions.

Comment: `*loonies  = ((dollars%2));` will not always work.  Consider $6

Comment: Ah, sure, you're right; I just went down the list without thinking. But apart from that particular one. :)

Comment: Easiest solution `*toonies  = 0; *loonies = dollars%5;`  (I suppose thats cheating)

Answer (score -1):

you need change:

`/* local variable definition of enter amount*/
    int dollars, *twenties, *tens, *fives, *toonies, *loonies;`

to

`/* local variable definition of enter amount*/
    int dollars, twenties, tens, fives, toonies, loonies;`

function pay_amount() like this:

`pay_amount(int *dollars,int *twenties,int *tens,int *fives,int *toonies,int *loonies)`

call function like this: `pay_amount(&dollars, &twenties, etc);`

and inside the pay_amount() like this:

`while (*dollars>=0);
 *dollars/20;
 *tens = ((*dollars%20)/10);`

Comment: In the function arguments you don't need to use `*dollars`, just `dollars`. And what is `while (*dollars>=0); *dollars/20;` supposed to do? Both statements are wrong.

Comment: it is pointer dereference, for example: pastebin.com/9fd3HAXB

Comment: The first statement `while (*dollars>=0);` will loop forever unless you have negative dollars. It should be `while (*dollars>0)`. The second statement `*dollars/20;` (which is in any case outside the `while` loop) issues a compiler warning because it does nothing. As for passing `*dollars` if you print the results after calling the function (and after correcting your bugs), you would have 0 dollars, which plainly is not the case. Dollars should be passed by value, not by reference.

Comment: I simply pointed out to the author to the obvious errors (language errors) logic errors I was not looking, can put a minus for me, you're right

Comment: stackoverflow asks you to explain why you down-vote (which I did) but I didn't know you are supposed to ask the author's permission.

Comment: certainly should not, I joked vote system improves the quality of answers and makes the process more interesting